# Is it possible to use GWT with (both) Java and PHP backend?

Tags: java, php, gwt

Ok, this is the scenario: I've developed a webapp running Java at backend, everything is working pretty well, but now I have to integrate a PHP module (boss requirement) within the whole system.
So, I need to know if both backends can co-exist in a single application and how can I accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it using [GwtPhp](http://www.gwtphp.com/).

Unlike most of the other frameworks, GwtPHP is a framework for both client and server part. Server part uses *PHP 5* - the most used web scripting language today.

Comment: The overview says this: _"User intefrace (client) is programmed in Java, then compiled by Google Web Toolkit (GWT) to browser-dependent JavaScript.

Server part uses PHP 5 - the most used web scripting language today."_

But it doesn't mention anything about using Java and PHP at the backend.

Comment: is your meaning of *backend equals server coding* ? then yes you can write php code at server side. but AFAIK for client side, you have to write code in java. As `GWT compiles java to java script`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant with backend. I thought it was same thing, that's why I didn't specify server-side coding. And yes, I know that for client side is a _must_ to write Java code in order to compile it into JavaScript :)

Answer (score 0):

It does not sound as if your boss is being reasonable!

There are some possibilities, though:

You could have the server-side entirely in PHP. Obviously you'd still have Java for the client-side because GWT requires it, but GWT can communicate via HTTP to any type of server using XML. You just can't use GWT's RMI-like interface if it's not a Java server.

Alternatively, you could have a separate PHP layer in your app, and the server-side Java itself can call it using HTTP.

Finally, (and more difficult, and experimental) there is a project to allow PHP to run in a Servlet Container, which may give you the ability to mix Java and php: see http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.java.php

Answer (score 0):

Two things spring to mind.

1) If the PHP app supports JSONP you could run it on a separate server and interact with it that way.

2) Stick the servlet container behind apache and proxy to the servlet container using something like the AJP connector.  This would mean that apache forwards the GWT requests to tomcat/jetty whatever and serves the PHP itself.